# Cannot create Temperature Data Source?

Tags: google-fit-api

I'm trying to create the temperature data source via REST and it keeps on failing with:

`Data type does not match well-known data type with the same name`

The data I'm sending in is:

```
{"application":{...Same as other working samples....},"dataType":{"field":[{"name":"body_temperature","format":"floatPoint"},{"name":"measurement_location","format":"integer","optional":true}],"name":"com.google.body.temperature"},"name":"Temperature Feed","type":"raw","dataStreamId":"raw:com.google.body.temperature:XXX"}
```

Per https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/health#body_temperature , I am not seeing any reason this shouldn't work -- what am I doing wrong?  Does temperature require special permission?

Thanks.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that measurement_location must be body_temperature_measurement_location in the REST request.  After changing that, it now works.